# Docker Logs invalid character/cannot parse issues

Tags: json, docker, logging, promtail

I use Docker (version 24.0.2) with multiple running containers, without the use of Kubernetes.
When I try to read logs from some of them using `docker logs` I get various errors such as:

```
Error grabbing logs: invalid character '\\x00' looking for beginning of value

Error grabbing logs: invalid character 'l' after object key:value pair

err="Could not parse timestamp from 'Error': parsing time \"Error\" as \"2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00\": cannot parse \"Error\" as \"2006\""
```

Some of the Docker images we use are sourced directly from Docker Hub, while others are custom-built using Python. And we haven't identified a discernible pattern regarding this behavior.
However, some containers log well, while others not.
Also, there are cases where I can retrieve logs using `docker logs --tail XX` but not using `docker logs --since XX` and vice versa.

docker/daemon.json:

```
{
  "data-root": "/storage/docker",
  "insecure-registries": [###, ###],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m",
    "max-file": "5"
  }
}
```

The issues I'm facing are:

1. Promtail is unable to read logs from containers experiencing these errors.
2. A very high CPU usage.

Would anyone happen to have insights or suggestions regarding these issues?

I attempted to resolve the issue of problematic characters in the log files by using the command  `sed -i 's/\x00//g' ./*.log*` to remove them, (both from the live log file and the archived ones) -- However, this action rendered the logs unreadable.
Many suggested solutions require deleting either the ~/.docker/ directory or the corrupted log files. Unfortunately, deleting these files isn't an option as I need to keep the logs.

Thank you!